# Flask Render Template Repeating HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask

I have a Flask app i'm integrating with JS. My app.py file looks like this:

```
import urllib
import requests
import time
from es import book

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
        current_origin = jsonify(book())
        return render_template('index.html', current_origin=current_origin)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True ,port=5000)
```

and the corresponding JS looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");

  $('#try-again').hide();

    // gets values from flask
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#results').append(data);
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
});
```

The console is printing the appropriate data from the call to `es import book` but the rendered page just keeps repeating the HTML with no data values (an endless repeat of HTML appended to the correct div but without the data I'm expecting). I tried several variations of `$('#results').append(data)` to include .html(data), .text(data), etc. but am not understanding what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what is happening. You need to separate the endpoints for rendering the page and returning the AJAX data. Try this:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/get_book")
def get_book():
    return jsonify(book())
```

Then change the `url` component of your AJAX call:

```
url: "{{ url_for('get_book') }}",
```

`jsonify()` returns a Response object. `render_template()` uses jinja to render the html page. Your code keeps inserting the same source HTML document into itself, triggering an infinite loop. You should only use `render_template()` to render an HTML page and jsonify() to send data to XHR calls.

Comment: Cool! A minor tweak and it worked. I had to change `url: "{{ url_for('get_book') }}",` to `url: "/get_book"` and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the help, I'll have to revisit the flask endpoints docs I missed this concept until now.

Comment: Ahh... OK. Actually I wasn't sure if your JS was within the rendered index.html file. The `{{ }}` syntax is Jinja2, so if it is a static resource that wouldn't work. Glad I could help.